# mix_docker npm not found when building the image

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework

With the last version of Alpine-erlang Linux image used in the `mix_docker` dependency I get a weird `npm command not found` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Takes me time to figure out that on the last version of Alpine npm package seems outside node.

With `nodejs-npm` package the error is solved.

In my Docker file:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main nodejs=6.10.3-r1 nodejs-npm=6.10.3-r1
```

For the segfault errors it seems that node version is conflicting with brunch when compiling assets.

Hope this helps others.